# I'd like to see one example where the conversion-type-id is looked up in the context of the entire postfix-expression

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, lookup, c++14

In [basic.lookup.classref]/7 (C++14) we have (emphasis is mine):

> If the *id-expression* is a *conversion-function-id*, its
>   *conversion-type-id* is first looked up in the class of the object expression and the name, if found, is used. **Otherwise** it is looked up
>   in the context of the entire *postfix-expression*. In each of these
>   lookups, only names that denote types or templates whose
>   specializations are types are considered.

I don't understand the need for the **Otherwise** above. Therefore, I'd like to see an example, where the *conversion-type-id* is looked up in the context of the entire postfix-expression.

Comment: N3797 has an example following this.

Comment: @chris This is an example where the conversion-type-id is found in the class of the object expression.

Comment: It doesn't take much to transform it into a name that is found in the call, but not the class. I guess I can anyway.

Comment: Hold on, it's a bit hard when the example isn't choosing `N::A` in the first place: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c56f7e8984a2019d

Comment: Something along the lines of `struct C {operator int();}; typedef int X; C c; c.operator X();` [Live example](http://rextester.com/VEZ97458).

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I'll accept this as answer.

Comment: Or `operator std::string()` vs `operator string` at the call-side.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something [like this](http://rextester.com/VEZ97458):

```
struct C {
    operator int() { return 42; }
};

typedef int X;

int main() {
  C c;
  c.operator X();  // calls c.operator int();
}
```

Clearly, the name `X` is not found in class `C`, but is found in the context of the expression where it's used.